# Uninstalling Mono and Monodevelop on Mac

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I had installed xcode 4 and wanted to explore monotouch so I followed the steps on the evaluation download page that mentioned to install the following in order:

1) iOS 4.3 SDK (which I already had)
2) Mono for Mac OS X
3) MonoDevelop
4) Monotouch Evaluation version

However since the latest release of monotouch does have some outstanding issues related to integration with interface builder, I decided to downgrade to xcode 3.2.6.

So I uninstalled xcode 4, restarted my mac and installed xcode 3.2.6. After that I uninstalled mono, monodevelop and reinstalled them but still when I click on MainWindow.xib from MonoDevelop it doesn't open the interface builder.

So my question is- how can I (1) uninstall mono and monodevelop fully (2) uninstall monotouch?

I am a newbie to Mac so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to set the default application for a .xib file;

- Find any .xib on your HDD in Finder and Right Click -> Get Info it.
- In the "Open With" section, change the drop down to "Interface Builder" and click "Change All..."

this is taken from [Geoff Norton's blog](http://blog.sublimeintervention.com/archive/2011/Apr-25.html)

Hope this helps.